# Draw saturation/brightness gradient

Tags: javascript, canvas, linear-gradients, color-picker, pixel-manipulation

I'm trying to draw the following gradient image in canvas, but there's a problem in the right bottom.

Desired effect:

[image]

Current output:

[image]

I'm probably missing something really simple here.

```js
function color(r, g, b) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  if (args.length == 1) {
    args.push(args[0]);
    args.push(args[0]);
  } else if (args.length != 3 && args.length != 4) {
    return;
  }
  return "rgb(" + args.join() + ")";
}

function drawPixel(x, y, fill) {
  var fill = fill || "black";
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(x, y, 1, 1);
  context.fillStyle = fill;
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("primary");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 256;
canvas.height = 256;

for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
    var r = 255 - y;
    var g = 255 - x - y;
    var b = 255 - x - y;
    drawPixel(x, y, color(r, g, b));
  }
}
```

```css
#primary {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="primary"></canvas>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqfpnfqq/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using gradients.

You can get the GPU to do most of the processing for you.The 2D composite operation `multiply` effectively multiplies two colours for each pixel. So for each channel and each pixel `colChanDest = Math.floor(colChanDest * (colChanSrc / 255))` is done via the massively parallel processing power of the GPU, rather than a lowly shared thread running on a single core (JavaScript execution context).

#### The two gradients

1. One is the background White to black from top to bottom

   `var gradB = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,255);
   gradB.addColorStop(0,"white");
   gradB.addColorStop(1,"black");`
2. The other is the Hue that fades from transparent to opaque from left to right

   ``` var swatchHue
   var col = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
   var gradC = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,255,0);
   gradC.addColorStop(0,``hsla(${hueValue},100%,50%,0)``);
   gradC.addColorStop(1,``hsla(${hueValue},100%,50%,1)``); ```

<sub>**Note** the above strings quote are not rendering correctly on SO so I just doubled them to show, use a single quote as done in the demo snippet.</sub>

### Rendering

Then layer the two, background (gray scale) first, then with composite operation "multiply"

```
ctx.fillStyle = gradB;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,255,255);
ctx.fillStyle = gradC;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,255,255);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

#### Only works for Hue

It is important that the color (hue) is a pure colour value, you can not use a random rgb value. If you have a selected rgb value you need to extract the hue value from the rgb.

The following function will convert a RGB value to a HSL colour

```
function rgbToLSH(red, green, blue, result = {}){
    value hue, sat, lum, min, max, dif, r, g, b;
    r = red/255;
    g = green/255;
    b = blue/255;
    min = Math.min(r,g,b);
    max = Math.max(r,g,b);
    lum = (min+max)/2;
    if(min === max){
        hue = 0;
        sat = 0;
    }else{
        dif = max - min;
        sat = lum > 0.5 ? dif / (2 - max - min) : dif / (max + min);
        switch (max) {
        case r:
            hue = (g - b) / dif;
            break;
        case g:
            hue = 2 + ((b - r) / dif);
            break;
        case b:
            hue = 4 + ((r - g) / dif);
            break;
        }
        hue *= 60;
        if (hue < 0) {
            hue += 360;
        }        
    }
    result.lum = lum * 255;
    result.sat = sat * 255;
    result.hue = hue;
    return result;
}
```

#### Put it all together

The example renders a swatch for a random red, green, blue value every 3 second.

<sub>Note that this example uses Balel so that it will work on IE</sub>

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 255;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

function drawSwatch(r, g, b) {
  var col = rgbToLSH(r, g, b);
  var gradB = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 255);
  gradB.addColorStop(0, "white");
  gradB.addColorStop(1, "black");
  var gradC = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 255, 0);
  gradC.addColorStop(0, `hsla(${Math.floor(col.hue)},100%,50%,0)`);
  gradC.addColorStop(1, `hsla(${Math.floor(col.hue)},100%,50%,1)`);

  ctx.fillStyle = gradB;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 255, 255);
  ctx.fillStyle = gradC;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 255, 255);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}

function rgbToLSH(red, green, blue, result = {}) {
  var hue, sat, lum, min, max, dif, r, g, b;
  r = red / 255;
  g = green / 255;
  b = blue / 255;
  min = Math.min(r, g, b);
  max = Math.max(r, g, b);
  lum = (min + max) / 2;
  if (min === max) {
    hue = 0;
    sat = 0;
  } else {
    dif = max - min;
    sat = lum > 0.5 ? dif / (2 - max - min) : dif / (max + min);
    switch (max) {
      case r:
        hue = (g - b) / dif;
        break;
      case g:
        hue = 2 + ((b - r) / dif);
        break;
      case b:
        hue = 4 + ((r - g) / dif);
        break;
    }
    hue *= 60;
    if (hue < 0) {
      hue += 360;
    }
  }
  result.lum = lum * 255;
  result.sat = sat * 255;
  result.hue = hue;
  return result;
}

function drawRandomSwatch() {
  drawSwatch(Math.random() * 255, Math.random() * 255, Math.random() * 255);
  setTimeout(drawRandomSwatch, 3000);
}
drawRandomSwatch();
```

To calculate the colour from the x and y coordinates you need the calculated Hue then the saturation and value to get the hsv colour (NOTE hsl and hsv are different colour models)

```
// saturation and value are clamped to prevent rounding errors creating wrong colour
var rgbArray = hsv_to_rgb(
    hue, // as used to create the swatch
    Math.max(0, Math.min(1, x / 255)),   
    Math.max(0, Math.min(1, 1 - y / 255))
);
```

Function to get r,g,b values for h,s,v colour.

```js
/* Function taken from datGUI.js 
   Web site https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage
   // h 0-360, s 0-1, and v 0-1
*/

function hsv_to_rgb(h, s, v) {
  var hi = Math.floor(h / 60) % 6;
  var f = h / 60 - Math.floor(h / 60);
  var p = v * (1.0 - s);
  var q = v * (1.0 - f * s);
  var t = v * (1.0 - (1.0 - f) * s);
  var c = [
    [v, t, p],
    [q, v, p],
    [p, v, t],
    [p, q, v],
    [t, p, v],
    [v, p, q]
  ][hi];
  return {
    r: c[0] * 255,
    g: c[1] * 255,
    b: c[2] * 255
  };
}
```

Comment: Using built-in gradients is a huge save: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/wyx7dfwn/). However, I'll also add a little circle to the SB box to choose a color and I need to find/calculate the color that is focused in the circle. I'm thinking about using `x,y` to calculate the focused color (the hard way), or maybe I can just read the pixel at the location of `x,y`. Any suggestions? I might post another question about this, soon.

Comment: @akinuri Have added what you need to the answer

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this with OpenGL, and Blindman67's answer was the only resource I found.
In the end, I did it by drawing 3 rectangles on top of each other.

1. All white
2. Transparent red to opaque red, horizontally
3. Transparent black to opaque black, vertically

[image: Resulting Gradient]

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** In the previous example, I've only created the gradient for red. I can also use the same method to create green and blue gradients after a little modification, but I can't use it to create gradients for random hues. Red, Green, and Blue are easy because while the one channel is `255`, other two have the same value. For a random hue, e.g. 140°, that is not the case. `H=140`translates to `rgb(0,255,85)`. Red and Blue can't have equal values. This requires a different and a more complicated calculation.

Blindman67's answer solves this problem. Using built-in gradients, you can easily create gradients for any random hue: 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/wyx7dfwn/). But being a very curious person, I wanted to do it the hard way anyway, and this is it:

(Compared to Blindman67's, it's very slow...)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/w7k19990/)

```js
function drawPixel(x, y, fillArray) {
  fill = "rgb(" + fillArray.join() + ")" || "black";
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(x, y, 1, 1);
  context.fillStyle = fill;
  context.fill();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("primary");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var grad1 = [ [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0] ]; // brightness

fillPrimary([255, 0, 0]); // initial hue = 0 (red)

$("#secondary").on("input", function() {
  var hue = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  var clr = hsl2rgb(hue, 100, 50);
  fillPrimary(clr);
});

function fillPrimary(rgb) {
  var grad2 = [ [255, 255, 255], rgb ]; // saturation
  for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {

      var grad1Change = [
        grad1[0][0] - grad1[1][0],
        grad1[0][1] - grad1[1][1],
        grad1[0][2] - grad1[1][2],
      ];
      var currentGrad1Color = [
        grad1[0][0] - (grad1Change[0] * y / 255),
        grad1[0][1] - (grad1Change[1] * y / 255),
        grad1[0][2] - (grad1Change[2] * y / 255)
      ];

      var grad2Change = [
        grad2[0][0] - grad2[1][0],
        grad2[0][1] - grad2[1][1],
        grad2[0][2] - grad2[1][2],
      ];
      var currentGrad2Color = [
        grad2[0][0] - (grad2Change[0] * x / 255),
        grad2[0][1] - (grad2Change[1] * x / 255),
        grad2[0][2] - (grad2Change[2] * x / 255)
      ];

      var multiplied = [
        Math.floor(currentGrad1Color[0] * currentGrad2Color[0] / 255),
        Math.floor(currentGrad1Color[1] * currentGrad2Color[1] / 255),
        Math.floor(currentGrad1Color[2] * currentGrad2Color[2] / 255),
      ];

      drawPixel(x, y, multiplied);
    }
  }
}

function hsl2rgb(h, s, l) {
  h /= 360;
  s /= 100;
  l /= 100;
  var r, g, b;
  if (s == 0) {
    r = g = b = l;
  } else {
    var hue2rgb = function hue2rgb(p, q, t) {
      if (t < 0) t += 1;
      if (t > 1) t -= 1;
      if (t < 1 / 6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
      if (t < 1 / 2) return q;
      if (t < 2 / 3) return p + (q - p) * (2 / 3 - t) * 6;
      return p;
    }
    var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
    var p = 2 * l - q;
    r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1 / 3);
    g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
    b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1 / 3);
  }
  return [
    Math.round(r * 255),
    Math.round(g * 255),
    Math.round(b * 255),
  ];
}
```

```css
#primary {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
#secondary {
  width: 256px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, yellow 16.66%, lime 33.33%, cyan 50%, blue 66.66%, violet 83.33%, red 100%);
}
#secondary::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 25px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="primary" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
<input type="range" min="0" max="360" step="1" value="0" id="secondary" />
```

---

Okay, so I've figured out what the problem is. While the vertical range is always between `[0,255]`, horizontal range is between `[0,r]`. So `g` and `b` can't be greater than `r` (Duh!).

[image]

```js
function color(r, g, b) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  if (args.length == 1) {
    args.push(args[0]);
    args.push(args[0]);
  } else if (args.length != 3 && args.length != 4) {
    return;
  }
  return "rgb(" + args.join() + ")";
}

function drawPixel(x, y, fill) {
  var fill = fill || "black";
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(x, y, 1, 1);
  context.fillStyle = fill;
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("primary");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 256;
canvas.height = 256;

for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
    var r = 255 - y;
    var g = b = r - Math.floor((x / 255) * r); // tada!
    drawPixel(x, y, color(r, g, b));
  }
}
```

```css
#primary {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="primary"></canvas>
```